# What's wrong with this property retrieval code?

Tags: javascript

```
var testobj = {
    whatever: "jeremy",
    alsotest: "wow"
};

for(name in testobj){
    document.writeln(name + ":" + testobj.name + "\n");
}
```

What I got from the browser is

```
whatever:undefined alsotest:undefined
```

There are two unexpected things: first why the values are undefined? second why the newline character is not printed at all?

Can anyone explain this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing a property using a `.` you must`*` provide an identifier that matches the name of the property. By using `testobj.name` you are accessing the property called `name` (which doesn't exist).

If you want to use a variable that contains a string that matches the name of the property, you must use square bracket notation.

```
testobj[name]
```

---

You can use any string in square bracket notation.

```
testobj["name"] === testobj.name;

function foo() {
    return "nam";
}

testobj[foo() + "e"] === testobj.name;
```

---

`*` "must" isn't *technically* true. It is possible to use `eval` (or something equivalent), but that way lies madness.

Comment: but since `name` is inside the `for in` loop, shouldn't it be substituted with actual property names?

Comment: @OneZero — No. Being in a loop doesn't change what `.something` means.

Answer (score 3):

In your case you are trying to get a non-existent property with name `"name"` out of `testobj`.

You should use square bracket notation instead: `testobj[name]`.

Comment: is `name` always a `string` object?

Comment: @OneZero if it's not a string, the language forces it to be a string.

Comment: @OneZero Makes sense, but it could also be an integer for an array for instance. Also, you have to understand the way strings are handled in javascript is specific.

Comment: and also, why there's no `newline` even I added it at the end?

Comment: @OneZero Because in HTML document `<br>` tags perform as new lines.

Comment: Because a new line has no more significance than any other kind of whitespace in HTML.